# Criteria for the gold tag badge

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges

The gold tag badge text says

> You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

My score is nearly 15k and I rarely read or answer questions not tagged with Java. I'm also sure that I've answered a lot of questions and scored mostly by answering. So I'd estimate my Java answers score to something like 10k and I wonder if I read the criterium wrong?

---

Changing the tag to "bug" as the text is confusing. Actually, I can't recall having seen "score" anywhere, so one may assume it means "rep" as this is the only well-known thing. **But "score" is fine, just make it to a link or add a tool-tip.**

I *though* it could mean upvotes rather then points, but even then... but i see my estimation was off by 106 upvotes.

I wouldn't have asked if there were no people with a lower score having the gold badge already. I thought I was rather extremely concentrated on a single tag, but I see that there are people even more concentrated.

Comment: Score means the net number of upvotes, not reputation. At the moment [you have a score of 894 in \[java\]](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RUoiP.png).

Comment: @Antony Could you show me how you found it out?

Comment: @maaartinus go to your SO profile, look at the section called "Tags" on the summary tab, or alternatively on the "Tags" tab.

Comment: @Antony: no, their *answer* score is lower than that. Use the tooltip.

Comment: Score does **not** mean number of upvotes. Score means the *sum of upvotes and downvotes*, so your absolute score for a tag. That's what score means on all of Stack Exchange. @Antony is being imprecise here and confusing you.

Comment: Whilst "score" isn't something that is often used or defined on SO it is different to rep, and the badge descriptions are fairly succinct - adding more words might not really help, and it would still need to be called "score" or something.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can't recall seeing "score" anywhere, but it's natural meaning is "points", which are called "rep" here, i.e., 10x answer upvotes - 2x answer downvotes. Whatever. **+++** Isn't Anthony saying the same thing as you do? In your picture I can see 894 as well.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid No need to add *any* words. Just make `score` to a *link* explaining what it means.  Then you can call any way you like (e.g., "Punkte") and it'll be perfectly clear.

Comment: @maaartinus: I see now that Antony used the phrase *net number*, which I missed, but I find the wording as they used it confusing still as it doesn't include a definition for *net* there (being upvotes minus downvotes).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see... I actually only cared about the number shown and has taken his "net" as simply meaning "the right thing". Now everything's clear, but nonethless I think there should be a link or a tooltip.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your total score *for answers in that tag*, where score is the net sum of all upvotes minus all downvotes you received on answers with the `java` tag. You must have provided at least 200 non-wiki answers to questions with the `java` tag to qualify.

It is not your *reputation* that is counted here.

You can find out your current score by hovering over the tag score in your profile, or by going to the `java` top users page; your account will always be listed in the top 20 answers rank even if you are not inside the top 20.

You currently have a score of 894 for 457 answers:

[image: answer score for OP]

The scores are updated once per 24 hours, around 03:00 UTC.

Comment: *The scores are updated once per 24 hours, around 03:00 UTC.* Is that still the case?

Comment: @GuerricP: usually, yes.

Comment: Seems almost impossible to get that many upvotes when all easy questions were already answered by [these people](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers) long before I joined SO.

Answer (score 10):

You need to have gotten at least 1000 **upvotes** (at least, as score == upvotes - downvotes) on non-community answers on questions that are tagged with that **tag**.

There should be at least 200 different questions where you got such upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/581205/maaartinus), you can see your current score for each tag:
[image: Current tag scores]

Hovering over the score (not the tag or the total post count) will give you a breakdown of the questions and answers score.

Alternatively, from the [main page for the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) you can click on "[Top Users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers)" in the info panel which will give you the stats for that tag. Your current position on those lists will tell you how you're doing (and you will always appear at the bottom of the "All Time" list if you have *any* score in that tag.
[image: Top users link]

Remember that the "Score" is actually a count of upvotes, not total rep gained, so is about 1/10th your rep. gain for the answers.